# toggle dropdown on click, hide others using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Not sure why this does not work but I have 3 different dropdowns built, an element to click to trigger the dropdown, all is working as expected. My issue is I want to hide all the others when one is clicked, I have this working to a degree, yes they are all hiding when I click the one I want open but now when I click that same one to "close" or "toggle off" it remains open? How can I ensure the second click closes the current dropdown? much appreciated if anyone can help me out with this one

HTML:

```
<div class = "dropdown-input-div">Click to Trigger open this one</div>

<ul class="form-dropdown-ul opened">
    <li class=" dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-0">
        <label class="dropdown-label">0-2 years ago</label></li>
    <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-1">
        <label class="dropdown-label">3-5 years ago</label></li>
    <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-2">
        <label class=" dropdown-label">5-8 years ago</label></li>
    <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-3">
        <label class="dropdown-label">8-10 years ago</label></li>
</ul>



<div class = "dropdown-input-div">Click to Trigger open this one</div>

<ul class="form-dropdown-ul">
    <li class=" dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-4">
        <label class="dropdown-label">10-12 years ago</label></li>
    <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-5">
        <label class="dropdown-label">12-16 years ago</label></li>
    <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-6">
        <label class=" dropdown-label">16-20 years ago</label></li>
</ul>



<div class = "dropdown-input-div">Click to Trigger open this one</div>

<ul class="form-dropdown-ul">
    <li class=" dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-4">
        <label class="dropdown-label">10-12 years ago</label></li>
    <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-5">
        <label class="dropdown-label">12-16 years ago</label></li>
    <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-6">
        <label class=" dropdown-label">16-20 years ago</label></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
  $('.form-dropdown-ul').hide();

$('.dropdown-input-div').on('click',function(){
  $('.form-dropdown-ul').hide();
  $(this).next('.form-dropdown-ul').toggle();
});
```

Comment: The `next()` element of the ul is a div, not another ul

Comment: You could try `$('+ .dropdown-input-div + .form-dropdown-ul', this).toggle();`, or `next().next().toggle()` which is a little ugly

Comment: Or i've seen people grab the index of the element in all the elements, go to the next index, and operate upon it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `$('ul').hide()` before your click function to hide all the `ul` elements. Then when you trigger `this` on the elements `next` `ul`, it will only toggle that elements child. Hide all siblings of the selected elements `next().siblings('ul')`.

Add:  `$(this).next().siblings("ul").hide();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("ul").hide();//<-- initially hide the UL elements
  $(".dropdown-input-div").click(function() {    
    $(this).next("ul").toggle(); //<-- toggle the next ul element of the selected DIV
    $(this).next().siblings("ul").hide(); //<-- hide all siblings of the selected ul
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-input-div">Click to Trigger open this one</div>

<ul class="form-dropdown-ul opened">
  <li class=" dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-0">
    <label class="dropdown-label">0-2 years ago</label></li>
  <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-1">
    <label class="dropdown-label">3-5 years ago</label></li>
  <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-2">
    <label class=" dropdown-label">5-8 years ago</label></li>
  <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-3">
    <label class="dropdown-label">8-10 years ago</label></li>
</ul>



<div class="dropdown-input-div">Click to Trigger open this one</div>

<ul class="form-dropdown-ul">
  <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-4">
    <label class="dropdown-label">10-12 years ago</label></li>
  <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-5">
    <label class="dropdown-label">12-16 years ago</label></li>
  <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-6">
    <label class=" dropdown-label">16-20 years ago</label></li>
</ul>



<div class="dropdown-input-div">Click to Trigger open this one</div>

<ul class="form-dropdown-ul">
  <li class=" dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-4">
    <label class="dropdown-label">10-12 years ago</label></li>
  <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-5">
    <label class="dropdown-label">12-16 years ago</label></li>
  <li class="dropdown-list-item" id="list-item-6">
    <label class=" dropdown-label">16-20 years ago</label></li>
</ul>
```